# Removing unused generated css files in compass

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

When you do a `compass compile` after renaming or deleting files the compiled files won't actually get removed. `compass clean` doesn't actually remove these files either since it only worries about cleaning up what is currently in use. That being said I don't want to do something like a `rm -rf /css/*` where css is my compiled folder either since that blows away all my files completely.

I am wondering if there is a way to just delete the "old" compiled files without touching anything currently in use.

Why?: if you have lots of scss files the generated files or sprite sheets might take some time to generate. This isn't too bad, but if you are then taking the generated files and creating some other derivative of it (maybe because you have some older build process or are generating docs or something else) then you need to completely regenerate all of it again. Blowing away all the files forces a complete regeneration; whereas, only removing un-needed files and then recompiling is extremely quick.

We are toying with the idea that blowing away all the files only on occasion by doing the following:

```
compass clean 
rm -rf css/* 
compass compile
```

But we are hoping for a better solution :).

Comment: what do you mean, if you import 'compass'; then you have all files you can import them individually like this @import 'compass/css3'; or do you mean files that you have created?

Comment: @ConnorMiles I meant that instead of deleting all generated css files I'd like to only remove the ones not in use. (revising question)

Comment: I'm going to have to question why you have so many compiled files for any given project that you actually *need* this.

Comment: @cimmanon if you have an entire website, with lots of modules, variations, marketing/event specific themes, custom page themes, etc etc etc you need more files. Furthermore, if you believe in refactoring you'll start restructuring things and moving stuff around. If you don't you end up with a mess. I think it also depends how small/specific you want to make some of your scss files.

Answer (score 0):

A shell script to remove the CSS files and generate new ones would look like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
compass clean
compass compile
```

Note that this particular script needs to be in the same directory as your project to work.  My script-fu is pretty weak, but I'm sure it could be modified to work anywhere without having to copy/paste it in every project.

Comment: But, won't this remove all my generated css files and completely recompile them?

Comment: It is the only way to do it with Compass.